# Hacer que textarea ocupe el 100% del ancho

Tags: html, bootstrap, css3

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Mensaje:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <textarea name="contenido" id="contenido" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje aquí" style="background-color: white;"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

El tema es que quiero que el textarea coja el ancho respecto al div con la clase container,o sea que ocupe todo el ancho. He probado la propiedad width; 100% , y no me lo coge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas utilizando Bootstrap, así que solo cambia el `<div class="col-lg-8">` por `<div class="col-lg-12">` y a el `textarea` agrégale la clase `form-control` como te dejo en el ejemplo, el primer textarea es como lo tienes en tu ejemplo, el segundo es el modificado para que utilice el 100% del div.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Mensaje:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <textarea name="contenido" id="contenido" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje aquí" style="background-color: white;"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Mensaje:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <textarea name="contenido" id="contenido" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje aquí" style="background-color: white;"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Agrega `min-width: 100%` al style del textarea.

```
<textarea style="min-width: 100%"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta poniendo ambos parámetros.

```html
<textarea style="min-width: 100%; width: 100%"></textarea>
```